# Search engine for website

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a search engine for a website. It's mostly a collection of HTML/CSS pages with some PHP. Now that's all there is. All of my content in on the pages.

From what I understand to be able to do this I would need to have the content on a Database, am I correct?

If so I was considering doing as such, creating a MySQL table with four columns "Keywords" "Titles" "Content" and "Link".

- Keywords - will hold the a word that if its in the query will show this as the most likely result.
- Titles - after searching Keywords searches the titles produce the most relevant results
- Content - should be a last resource for finding something as it will be messier I believe
- Link - is just the link that belongs to the particular row.

I will be implementing it with PHP and MySQL, and it will be tiresome to put all the content, titles etc into a db. Is this a good method or should I be looking at something else?

Thanks.

---------------EDIT-------------------

Lucene seems like a good option, however even after reading the Getting started and looking around a bit on the web I cant understand how it works, can someone point me somewhere that explains this in a very very basic manner? Especially taking in consideration I do not know how to compile anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Writing a (good) search engine is a fairly difficult task.  There are many existing solutions that might worth considering - http://www.sphider.eu/ is one that might be suitable.

Comment: Colin, thank you for your suggestion it is just what I needed, very appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Building a search engine from scratch is painful. It is an interesting task, indeed, so if it is for learning, then do it!

However, if you just need a good search function for your web site, please use something that others have done for you. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) is one option.

Answer (score 1):

> [Sphinxsearch](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) is an open-source full-text search server, designed from the ground up with performance, relevance (aka search quality), and integration simplicity in mind.
>
> Sphinx lets you either batch index and search data stored in an SQL database, NoSQL storage, or just files quickly and easily — or index and search data on the fly, working with Sphinx pretty much as a database server.

Comment: The only thing to point out is that, of course, it requires to be installed on the server (which he could or could not do, I do not know).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your pages are static HTML. You can do two things at once and transfer the content of the pages in the DB, so that they will be generated on the fly by reading their content from the DB.

Anyway, I think your strategy is OK at least for a basic search engine. Also have a look into [MySQL fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL fulltext search will be the easiest to setup but it will be a lot slower than [Sphinxsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/). Even Lucene is slower than Sphinx. So if speed is a criteria, I would suggest taking time out to lean and implement Sphinx.

In one of his presentations, Andrew Aksyonoff (creator of Sphinx) presented the following
benchmarking results. Approximately 3.5 Million records with around 5 GB of text were used
for the purpose.

> ```
>             MySQL Lucene Sphinx
> ```
>
> Indexing time, min 1627   176    84
>
> > Index size, MB              3011  6328   2850
> >
> > > Match all, ms/q              286  30     22
> > >
> > > > Match phrase, ms/q           3692 29     21
> > > >
> > > > > Match bool top-20, ms/q       24   29    13

Apart from a basic search, there are many features that make Sphinx a better solution for
searching. These features include multivalve attributes, tokenizing settings, wordforms,
HTML processing, geosearching, ranking, and many others

Answer (score 0):

[Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) is a pure PHP implementation of search which is quite useful.

Another search option is [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which is based on lucene, but does a lot of the heavy lifting for you in order to produce more google like results. This is probably your easiest option, besides using Mysql MyISAM fulltext search capabilities.